# Clickable div will not show

Tags: html, css

I want the whole div clickable, but it will not show. I want it to change when hovered as well. I believe I have used this same coding before and it has worked, not sure why I am having issues.

```
<div class="clickable_one">
    <a href="#"> </a>
</div>

div.clickable_one {
float:right;
}

div.clickable_one a {
    position:absolute;
    width:120px;
    height:30px;
    text-decoration:none; 
    background-image:url("images/forums_link copy.png"); 
}

div.clickable_one a:hover {
    position:absolute;
    width:120px;
    height:30px;
    text-decoration:none; 
    background-image:url("images/forums_link_2 copy.png"); 
}
```

Comment: From your CSS rules the only thing "changing" is the link within the `div`.

Comment: maybe a jsfiddle would help.

Comment: Also, as @MelanciaUK said, you are only targeting the <a> with the hover event, so it is the only thing changing on hover. As a side note, if you a have a hover event, you dont need to repeat every property that is not changing with the event.

Comment: Nothing is being shown in the first place... that is my problem. And, ne1410s, I am.

Comment: Check the use of 'position:Absolute' you need to make the parent 'relative'. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/c5f7sbzk/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using `float:right` on your `div` and `position:absolute` on your `<a>` which forced everything to move on right corner of screen. If you use **InspectElement** you will have clear view. I placed a border around your `div` as example to check location of `div`

I'v updated your **CSS** a bit and content is showing.

```
div.clickable_one 
{
border: 2px solid blue;
}

div.clickable_one a {
    width:120px;
    height:30px;
    text-decoration:none; 
    background-image:url("images/forums_link copy.png"); 
}

div.clickable_one a:hover 
{
    width:120px;
    height:30px;
    text-decoration:underline; 
    background-image:url("images/forums_link copy.png"); 
}
```

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/smCiq)**